# Syntax error for basic task on vs code for Mac

Tags: python

[image: enter image description]

Trying to run basic code in python but coming across this currently. It might have something to do with the path at which python is located. I have added the path where python is to the settings in vs code but may have done it incorrectly.

Comment: Line 7 has to be `greeting =` and not `greeting -`

Comment: You need to exit the Python REPL before you can run the script. Close the terminal, use the green button at the top

Answer (score 0):

The error is in line 7: `greeting - 'hello, {}'.format(who_to_greet)`.

You have subtracted the string `'hello, {}'.format(who_to_greet)` from `greeting` instead of assigning it.

Change it to `greeting = 'hello, {}'.format(who_to_greet)` and you should be fine.

Comment: That's not what the traceback says is the issue

Comment: Oh, you're right. The subtraction will cause a NameError.

Answer (score 0):

Your greet function is not defined on python terminal. You can execute the function from terminal and use that function or You have to exit the python terminal and run the file from the directory.
Use below code to exit the python shell.

```
>>>exit()
```

After exiting. Run your python file from the terminal like below.

```
>python hello.py
```

N.B. You can't run function in the terminal which is in your python script. To use a function in terminal, you have to execute that function from terminal also.